# Case statement throwing invalid argument type error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I'm working on a snowflake query.

```
Case when x = a then 1
       When ifnull(a,' ') <> b then 1 end as
```

I'm hiding the original column names.

The above case statement throwing error

`invalid argument types for function '<>':(Row(varchar(25),varchar(1)),varchar(11))` .

Please help me!

Comment: Please show us some sample data and expected output your attempt is supposed to generate

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it worked, please check your code.

```
create or replace  table test(x  varchar2, a varchar2, b varchar2)          ;

select a, b, case when x = a then 1
             when ifnull(a, '') <> b then 1 end from test;
```

Comment: I think we need to do cast based on error, i tried but no use

Comment: Can you please give some sample data for the query, where you are getting the error.